# Concatenate network path + variable (name of the folder)

Tags: powershell, cmd, directory

How can I concatenate this network path with this variable entered by the user (it will be a full network path)?

So the user type the new folder name, for example: Folder-123 (will be stored in the variable $pjname)

```
Copy-Item "\\SERVER\Work_3rd\R Drive Structure\Project No\MDCXXXX" -Destination "\\SERVER\Work_3rd" -Recurse

write-host "Folder has been created. Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)    

Write-Host "Please enter the project name: "
$pjname = Read-Host
Write-Output "New Folder will be: $pjname"

Rename-Item -Path "\\SERVER\Work_3rd\MDCXXXX" -NewName $pjname

write-host "Folder has been renamed. Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)

$pathToTemplate = '\\SERVER\Work_3rd\R Drive Structure\Project No\MDCXXXX'

$rootPath2 = '\\SERVER\Work_3rd\'

$rootPath = -join ($rootPath2, $pjname) # this concatenates the new project 
name on to the root folder path**

# $rootPath += $pjname  # this concatenates the new project name on to the 
root folder path

If(Test-Path $rootPath)
{
$CurrentACL = (Get-Item $pathToTemplate).GetAccessControl('Access')
$CurrentACL | Set-Acl -Path $rootPath
}
```

This new folder stored in $pjname should have a network path like `\\\SERVER\Work-3rd\ + FOLDER NAME`. For example `\\\SERVER\Word-3rd\Folder-123`

The PowerShell is not finding the final path of the new folder so the permission is not being applied on it.

---

I'm trying in a test area and getting this problem below:

```
Folder has been renamed. Press any key to continue...

Get-Acl : Cannot find path '\\SERVER\test-area\Test-123' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\felipe.sa\Desktop\Script\NewProjectFolder\NewProject-WP_- 
_ProductionV3.ps1:279 char:8
+ $acl = Get-Acl $NewNetworkPath
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\felipe.sa\Desktop\Script\NewProjectFolder\NewProject-WP_- 
_ProductionV3.ps1:282 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Have a look at the cmdlets `Join-Path` and `Test-Path`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a new directory in that share path, or rename a directory? It looks like you're trying to rename a directory.

My guess it isn't working because you are missing the trailing "\" in your path. Here is some sample code that adds a user supplied variable to a network path:

```
$MyRootPath     = "\\SomeServer\Dir1\Dir2\"
Write-Host "Enter Dir Name"
$myAnswer       = Read-Host
```

I typed "hello" when prompted for new directory..

```
$finalAnswer    = $myAnswer.Trim()
$NewNetworkPath = ("{0}{1}" -f $MyRootPath, $finalAnswer)
$NewNetworkPath
```

returns:

```
\\SomeServer\Dir1\Dir2\hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are concatenating paths, escpecially those supplied by end users, stick to a utility that can do *most* of the heavy lifting. Use the [combine method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) as string concatenation has several pitfalls that have to be needlessly mitigated.

```
[io.path]::combine('\\server\share', 'newfolder')
```

The combine method will take the path parts, as an array, and build a proper path. Note this does not validate if the path exists. It can deal with trailing path separators well. These next commands yield the same result.

```
[io.path]::combine('\\server\share\', 'newfolder')
[io.path]::combine('\\server\share', 'newfolder')
```

Beware leading path separators though:

> If the one of the subsequent paths is an absolute path, then the combine operation resets starting with that absolute path, discarding all previous combined paths.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Matt & oze4! A weird problem happened now. I used the solution of oze4 and sometimes it works and sometimes not. Would it be the string entered by the user?

When it worked the folder name was 'MDX1111 - XXXX Xxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxx' - 32 characters. I ran the code again using the folder name 'MDX1112 - Xxxxxx Xxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxx' - 35 characters and got this error below:

```
Get-Acl : Cannot find path '\\SERVER\Work_Block_A\MDX1112 - Xxxxxx Xxxxxxx 
Xxxxxxxxxx' because it does not
exist.
At C:\Users\felipe.sa\Desktop\Script\NewProjectFolder\NewProject-WP_- 
_ProductionV1.ps1:125 char:8
+ $acl = Get-Acl $NewNetworkPath
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\felipe.sa\Desktop\Script\NewProjectFolder\NewProject-WP_- 
_ProductionV1.ps1:128 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Any thoughts?

Thank you.